# Python-Type Error-Encoding error

Tags: python, typeerror

what this error bytes like object is required not str..?

```
tr=utf_string.encode('utf8')
tr=tr.replace(r',','')
```

I tried changing it to replaceb. Does not work

Comment: Please paste the actual error, don't just vaguely describe it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page before posting

Comment: As a side note, it's pretty misleading to call something `utf_string` when it's a Unicode `str`, not a UTF-8 or UTF-16 or UTF-32 `bytes`, and that may in fact be part of what confused you here.

Answer (score 5):

After performing `tr=utf_string.encode('utf8')`, `tr` is a `bytes` object. Methods on `bytes` objects expect `bytes` arguments, not `str` arguments. So you need to make the arguments to `replace` [`bytes` literals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), using the `b` prefix (you don't need the `r` prefix here; it's not a regex, and there are no backslashes in it in any event):

```
tr = tr.replace(b',', b'')
```

Comment: I think mentioning regex here is just going to confuse the OP. They're not the only thing raw string literals are used for, and he may well not know anything about regexes…

Comment: @abarnert: I mention it to explain why I removed the `r` prefix on the string they were passing to `replace`; they had no reason at all to use it, which makes me suspect they were copying from some more complicated code using regexes. While raw string literals can be used for any old reason, the only *common* reasons to use them are for regexes and Windows paths (and I strongly encourage *always* using them for those cases). If they don't know anything about them, it's sufficient to say that it's not needed here.